# What is the microscopic state of an electron in a charged insulator?

Tags: condensed-matter

Assume we put an extra electron in a neutral insulator (on surface or in bulk). The insulator becomes charged. What would be the quantum state of that electron?

Is it confined somewhere between the atoms? Or described in terms of the Bloch functions?

In terms of bands, the extra electron should go into the conduction band, and thus become mobile. But can it be mobile in an insulator?

Answer (score 0):

Electrons in the insulator are tightly bound to the ions.The extra electron on an insulator cannot move as conduction band is completely empty for an insulator. 
So technically the electron will be localized wherever its placed on an 
insulator.As it does not belong to or correspond to any specific atom,
you cannot assign quantum numbers to that electron.Also in a practical case
such extra electron wont be there on the insulator for long as it will attract
stray ions(positive charges) and will become neutralized.So the lifetime
of such electron(or excess charge) depends on the environment of the insulator.
Like humidity etc.Also check this similar question which might be helpful:
[Excess charge on an insulator and conductor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38488/excess-charge-on-an-insulator-and-conductor)

Comment: I don't quite understand the argument that the electron will be localized because the conduction band is empty. How can I see it? Naively, I could say the extra electron(s) go into the conduction band, and it's not empty anymore.

Comment: The excess electron sits at the fermi energy of the material it resides on.If you put an extra electron on a conductor where fermi energy lies inside the band (or in the conduction band for that matter) the electron can move around and thus the excess charge will be uniformly distributed over the conductor.Whereas in case of an insulator,the fermi energy is in the band gap, which means that there are no free states where the electron can move around.(which is why insulators don't conduct)So now your excess electron on the insulator is at the fermi energy which is in the band gap,so localized.