# What is the difference between charged body and conductors?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, conductors

In charged bodies,charges can be uniformly distributed all over it's volume, but in conductors charges always lies on it's surface.

Please tell me the difference between charged bodies and conductors?
And tell me how can bodies be uniformly charged while charges reside only on surface in conductors?

Comment: `in conductors charges always lies on it's surface` - only true in case of statics.

Comment: yes sir,we are considering only electrostatics.i have categorized it in electrostatics only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excess charge on an insulator and conductor](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38488/excess-charge-on-an-insulator-and-conductor)

Comment: @John Rennie i have never seen that question but after seeing it now i can clearly see that is completely irrelevant to the question i just asked,it is based on the conduction of charges in conductor while mine is on different between conductor and charged bodies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is charge can flow in a conductor.

Consider what would happen if we started with a solid sphere of metal with excess positive charge initially uniformly distributed through the volume. There would be an electric field in the volume, and so the charges would move.  Eventually all the charge will be on the surface.

The charge can also move along the surface.  So in electrostatics the constraint is not just that the charge is on the surface, but that the potential is the same value everywhere on the surface of a conductor. (So not necessarily uniform unless the object has a lot of symmetry.)

Comment: thank you very much for replying sir,but don't charges move in charged bodies?why?what makes the difference?is the material with which they are made of?

Comment: Yes, the material they are made of matters.  Some materials are conductors (copper), while others are insulators (glass).  When discussing electrostatics, insulators (but not conductors) can have charge embedded in their volume.

Comment: i think i got it now,when it is given charged solid sphere we should take it as an insulator which has charge density throughout it's volume while if it is mentioned charged solid metal sphere, now any charge can reside only on the surface of the metal sphere so electrically it behaves like a solid hollow sphere,am i right sir?

Comment: yep, sounds like you understand

Answer (score 1):

In electrostatics we study static electrons, which are not moving so a charged body and a conductor are symmetric. Until we apply electric field or potential the electrons can not move.

Comment: A charged body has either an excess or a deficiency of electrons (in ordinary, everyday situations). That means there will be a net electric field. What do you mean by "a charged body and a conductor is symmetric?" Excess charge behaves differently in conductors and non-conductors, which is the focus of the question.